# i for i syntax in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm working through a module on NLP, and they use this syntax to "create a dictionary that maps us from a word to its index in the word embeddings matrix."

```
index = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(english_words)}
```

I've never seen a loop that uses *i for i* before. I believe I understand what it's doing (taking every word at index i, and mapping it to the corresponding word in english_words. But, how does this syntax actually work? Do other languages use this syntax, or is this python-specific?

Comment: Note that `i for i` isn't a fundamental element of this expression. The basic structure of a dictcomp is `{KEY: VALUE for VARIABLE(s) in ITERABLE}`.  So `i` alone isn't the output (`word: i` is), and you are looping over both `i` and `word` together (since `enumerate()` produces 2-element tuples).

Comment: If it helps, you could also write it as `{word: i for (i, word) in enumerate(english_words)}` since `i, word` is a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of dictionary comprehension.

**What it is actually doing is:**

For every word in `english_words`, separate the key (*word*) and value (*i*), and create an entry in the dictionary `index` of the form `word: i`

**Equivalent to:**

```
index = {}
counter = 0
for word in english_words:
   index[word] = counter
   counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called list comprehension. List comprehension is an elegant way to define and create lists based on existing lists. You can find out more about list comprehension [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

Other is enumerate(), this just unpacks the list. Returns index and value for the list. Same as .items() gives for dicts. Will get a better idea about this [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate)